# Passing a callback and other parameters to jQuery ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, callback

I wrote a function which I'm allowing a callback to be passed to. I then want to execute that with both the ajax repsonse, and another parameter.

My problem is the the callback is executed, and when I step through the code, it looks like the function is called with the proper parameters, however when actually stepping in to the callback function, the first parameter takes the value of whatever I assign to the second argument, and the second argument is `undefined`.

Here is my function:

```
namespace = {
fetch : function(sr, count, callback) {
    srCount = count ? count : '25'
    var sub;
    if (sr == 'frontpage'){
        sub = '';
    }else{
        sub = 'foo/' + sr + '/';
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.example.com/"+sub+ ".json?count=" + count,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            callback.call(msg, count)
        }
    })
};
```

Now, when I call it like this:

```
mynamespace.fetch($(this).attr('href'), 25, true, another namespace.createPost);
```

I would expect `callback.call(msg, count)` to resolve to `callback.call(/*the ajax response*/, 25);`

However, when I run it, I get `msg == 25` and `count == 'undefined'`. I'm at a loss for why...

Comment: `mynamespace.fetch($(this).attr('href'), 25, true, another namespace.createPost);`. What's `true` for?

Comment: A remnant from old code that I copied and pasted... not actually used. Editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.call` calls a function with explicit context given by the first argument, so `callback.call(msg, count)` calls the callback function with `msg` set as context (the `this` value inside the callback function for this call) and `count` as a first argument.

So you probably want `callback( msg, count )` or `callback.call( namespace, msg, count );` which means that `this` inside the callback will refer to `namespace` for that call.

Comment: so put another way, `call` accepts X+1 parameters, where the first is the namespace the function will run in, and the remaining X are passed to the variable?

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski Well if by namespace you mean the value of `this` in the called function then yes, the arguments passed start after that either way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax()` function has a context parameter, which you can use for this purpose.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.example.com/"+sub+ ".json?count=" + count,
  context: "hello",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg)
  {

    // here 'this' will be the 'hello' you specified for context while making the call.

    callback.call(msg, count)
  }
})
```